# Ionic redirect view in javascript file

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I faced redirect view issue in Ionic V1 when running the redirect command Android device, when running with Google Chrome, it can redirect to the specific view, but in device it become white screen, seen like cannot find the specific view. I am using the command as below to redirect the view

```
window.location = '/?#/app/account';
```

I cant redirect the view with any Angular command like `$location.path()` or `$state.go()`, because the redirect happen in standalone JavaScript file.

How could I redirect to home view or specific view in standalone JavaScript file?